# Authoritative list of tags without textnode

Tags: tags, textnode

I'm looking for an authoritative list of tags that don't have a textnode, e.g.: `img`, `br`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently these are so called `void elements` and are listed here: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements